Use Selenium WebDriver to cancel a download in progress
I am trying to write python code to cancel a download in progress using selenium. I previously used the code supplied here to do this but these days (chrome Version 128.0.6613.138) the cancel button is hidden inside a dropdown menu.
I can display the dropdown menu easily enough:
w.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot."                         +"querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#more-actions').click()")
Image of dropdown list in chrome downloads
But the task of identifying and clicking on an item within the dropdown list has stumped me completely. Can anybody help please?
